# FLatlist dose'nt render at all

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make 2 tabs in which each will render a different flatlist on their own, but for some reason, after I pass my API data to a state ('apidata') it won't render flatlist while I can see a log of ApiData's objects. Can anybody observe my problem with rendering data?

here is the sample of data

```
Object {
  "0": Object {
    "comment": "",
    "end_time": "2021-09-04T11:59:03Z",
    "enter": "49000.00000000",
    "exchange": "BINANCE",
    "leverage": 120,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "per": "USDT",
    "position": "LONG",
    "risk_level": "Crazy",
    "stop_loss": "48700.00000000",
    "symbol": "BTC",
    "target_1": "52700.00000000",
    "target_2": "68000.00000000",
    "target_3": "0.00000000",
  },
  "1": Object {
    "comment": "",
    "end_time": "2021-09-14T06:00:00Z",
    "enter": "495000.00000000",
    "exchange": "binanace",
    "leverage": 15,
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "per": "btc/usdt",
    "position": "LONG",
    "risk_level": "High",
    "stop_loss": "48000.00000000",
    "symbol": "btc",
    "target_1": "52000.00000000",
    "target_2": "5300.00000000",
    "target_3": "0.00000000",
  },
```

and here is my code which I tried Hi to see if my const works after I tap on its tab.

```
const Crypto = (apidata) => {
  console.log(apidata, "log e crypto");
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "red",
        justifyContent: "center",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Hi</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={apidata}
        scrollEnabled
        keyExtractor={apidata?.risk_level}
        renderItem={(item) => {
          return <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>{apidata?.stop_loss}</Text>;
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlatList receives an Array of data not an object of objects. Consider transforming the data received from the api to an array of objects.

Comment: Good point, but apidata is an array before I pass it to the crypto component is there something that I miss which change its format to an object? 

this is how I pass it as a prop
 {activeTab == "Crypto" && <Crypto {...apidata} />}

Comment: when you destructure in this way {...apidata} you are basically creating an object with the content of apidata. try this: <Crypto apidata={apidata} /> and it will pass apidata as it is

Comment: Thanks for the help it works now! 

is there anyway I could learn this kind of basics in to prevent such issues in future?

Comment: I would recommend reading the documentation for the components you use and using typescript. Using typescript would let you know that the type you're using is wrong (it would tell you it needs an array but you're passing an object for example). If my solution works for you, please accept the answer so we can close this question.

Comment: I never read typescript and how we can use it maybe if you can suggest a decent source to do so

Comment: @navidabasi this should be helpful https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript